# JavaFX Image / ImageView NullPointerException

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

I want to load a image in my program but i throughs an exception.
I tried to change the file-path but it doesn't change anything. 
and I convert the image form a jpg to a png file, but nothing has changed
[image]

```
public class Main extends Application {


   static int WIDTH = 800;
   static int HIGHT = 600;

   private  Player player;
   final static Image back = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("src/images/background.png").toString());

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
       final ImageView background = new ImageView(back);
       final Group root = new Group();

       primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, WIDTH, HIGHT));
       primaryStage.show();

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
}
```

The Exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.game.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:21)
... 3 more
```

Comment: The path is wrong. You probably need to remove `"src"`, but there's no way to know for sure without knowing the structure of your project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
final static Image back = new Image("/images/background.png");
```

You can directly use :

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView("/images/background.png");
```

Just make sure the image is located in a folder which is on the `classpath` or `buildpath`, whatever you wanna call it.

Comment: this change nothing , I'll post the file-structor